# jQuery Drag-and-drop upload... anywhere to be found?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a good jQuery Drag-and-drop file upload plugin? Not images... i am looking to upload a .txt file upon drag-and-drop to the area... simple as that.

I know there are few jquery drag-and-drop but they deal with multiple file uploads or drag-n-drop images...

Comment: Aren't images just files?  If a particular control accepts images, will it accept other file types?  If it supports multiple file uploads, can you restrict it to single?  What controls have you looked at, and what were your reasons for rejecting them?

Comment: bare in mind that any drag and drop and multiple file upload require flash player to be installed in the user's browser, even if the swf is not visible, those scripts use a swf file to handle the files. maybe the script will start using native support for chrome but I think flash is still a requirement

Comment: @Juan: no they don't.  hence the HTML 5 part...

Comment: @Chris Lively, true, that's why I mentioned native support, but you still need a flash fallback for most IE versions. I didn't know plupload could handle different technologies to do the same task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jquery file uploader http://github.com/valums/file-uploader

and plupload http://www.plupload.com/ are good ones.